# Number of tables required to decompose a function into BCNF

Tags: databases

I know this is not a question answer posting site, but for sake of explaining my doubt I will like to post a question

Say you are given table like

> R(A,B,C,D,E,F)= {AB→C, BC → A, AC→ B , B → D , D→ E }

Now how will you figure out how many tables are needed to decompose this function in $BCNF?$

Is there any ***short formula*** by which we can figure this out directly or do we have to do this in the hard way like i have shown below-->

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated, specially if there is some $formula$ by which we can do it within some seconds or such. Thank you.. :)

---

And downvoters (if any)  PLEASE do mention the reason of downvote if you wish to downvote.